# How to use node-opcua to read from OPC DA Server?

Tags: node.js, opc, opc-ua, opc-da, node-opcua

The repository page for `node-opcua` says it supports `DataAccess`. But I was not able to find any example in which it connects to an OPC DA server and reads data.

So far I've tried the [server_with_da_variables](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/68b1b57dec23a45148468fbea89ab71a39f9042f/documentation/server_with_da_variables.md) example. I have been able to read its data using [sample_client](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/68b1b57dec23a45148468fbea89ab71a39f9042f/documentation/sample_client.js).

Is the method same as connecting to OPC UA Server? Do we use endpoint URL and create session and read using NodeId, or is the procedure different?

Comment: It supports OPC UA Data Access, not OPC DA. The OPC classic specifications (OPC DA + OPC AE + OPC HDA) are almost 20years old. The latests specification: OPC UA specify Data Access, Alarms & Conditions and Historical Data Access

Answer (score 2):

The "DataAccess" probably refers to Data Access features in OPC Unified Architecture (Part 8 of the OPC UA spec), and not to the COM-based OPC DA.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ZbynekZ.

While confusing, when someone refers to an "OPC-DA" server they are referring to a COM-based server 99% of the time.

If you want to access a COM-based server through OPC-UA you'll need to put a UA wrapper application in front of it.

Comment: do you know of any node based OPC DA Client?